# Getting value of select element using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="question-set">
      <div class="row question">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <select class="form-control" name="type[]">
            <option value="Teacher feedback">Teacher feedback</option>
            <option value="Genral Question">Genral Question</option>
            <option value="Informative Question">Informative Question</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="questions[]" placeholder="Enter the question here" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row question">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <select class="form-control" name="type[]">
            <option value="Teacher feedback">Teacher feedback</option>
            <option value="Genral Question">Genral Question</option>
            <option value="Informative Question">Informative Question</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="questions[]" placeholder="Enter the question here" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In short there is a select tag with name type[] and a text input field names questions[]. I need to pass the values to a php page as an ajax call to insert into the database. I have the following AJAX code..

```
  $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "feedback_create_form_process.php",
          data: {"questions": $("input[name='questions[]']").val(), "type": $("select option:selected").val()},
          success: function(data){
            alert(data);
          }
        });
```

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php
  include 'con.php';
  if (isset($_POST) && sizeof($_POST)) {
    $question = $_POST['questions'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];

    echo count($question);
    foreach( $question as $key => $n ) {
      $result = $con->query("insert into form question(null, ".$question[$key].", ".$n.")");
    }
  }
?>
```

The count is returned as 1. It sends only the first question and not the array. I want the values in an array so i can do an insert in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Documented in JQuery .Val()

> Description: Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements.

You can use

```
var values = $("input[name='questions[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

or

```
var values = [];
$("input[name='questions[]']").each(function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Do i do the same thing for select element?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of jQuery's `map()` function to return the values as an array, like so:

```
var questions = $("input[name='questions[]']").map(function() {return $(this).val()}).get();
var types = $("select[name='type[]']").map(function() {return $(this).val()}).get();

$.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "feedback_create_form_process.php",
     data: {"questions": questions, "type": types},
     success: function(data){
         alert(data);
     }
});
```

**EDIT:** Realizing a similar solution was provided by [ABDU_GO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475257/abdu-go). I find my script to be a bit more readable, however if you find this to be your solution, I'd suggest accepting his answer.

Comment: map function is jquery works like a charm, But when i pass it with the data JSON array, the AJAX call does not seem to work.

Comment: Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.feedback_create_form.php
TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.
r.param/e()
jquery.min.js:4
xb()
jquery.min.js:4
xb()
jquery.min.js:4
xb()
jquery.min.js:4
xb()
jquery.min.js:4
r.param()
jquery.min.js:4
.ajax()
jquery.min.js:4
<anonymous>
feedback_create_form.php:28
r.event.dispatch()
jquery.min.js:3
r.event.add/q.handle()